# Swift threading issue

Tags: swift

I have an issue with the way / order in which threads run in swift with regards to custom objects. Let's say I create a UIView with some simple code:

```
import UIKit

class ExampleObject: UIView {

    var list = [Int]()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        list = [1,2,3]
    }

}
```

Now I try to get back the value of the list variable after I create it in my View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let eg = ExampleObject()
    self.view.addSubview(eg)

    print(eg.list)
}
```

It will print out `[]` even though clearly the minute I've created the object it should be `[1,2,3]`. However, if I call it at some later time from a different function I will get the correct value. I'm guessing this has something to do with the order in which things execute in swift so that I can for example change the color of a button after I've added to the view... But I need to get the actual value of list because in my custom object it is calculating something quite complicated. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Why do you use the `draw`-method for this purpose? Try to call this method implicitly after view added.

Comment: I need to use draw because the value I'm trying to retrieve is actually related to subviews I'm creating in the custom object.

Comment: don't create this objects in `draw`-method. Override `didMoveToSuperview()` instead.

Comment: "even though clearly the minute I've created the object it should be [1,2,3]" ... No, it's set to `[1,2,3]` not when the object is created, but rather when that view is rendered. But it's not rendered by the time you call `print(e.g..list)`, so it's not `[1,2,3]` yet.

Comment: I got it to work if I use an async task with and check on completion... Works ok I guess

Comment: @AntersBear - Merely dispatching asynchronous sounds a bit fragile. I wonder if a delegate-protocol pattern might make more sense here (e.g. the view informs the view controller when the calculation is done). Or observer pattern. Or some completion closure. It's hard to say on the basis of the modest information provided thus far.